# rotate single image to multiples angles with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have one round image. I need to rotate this image in 1 degree steps. i.e. 60 rotated images of single image. How may I do this with imagemagick ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible.

This one will create a right rotating pic series.

```
for i in $(seq -w 1 60)
do 
    convert -rotate ${i} orig-image.jpg pic_rotated_${i}.jpg
done
```

If you would like to have it left rotated, just put a `-` sign in the `-rotate` value.

```
for i in $(seq -w 1 60)
do 
    convert -rotate -${i} orig-image.jpg pic_rotated_${i}.jpg
done
```

I chose `seq` to generate the number series with leading zero which makes it easier to sort. One could also use `{1..60}` instead of `$(seq...)`.

Comment: Ah, nine seconds before me. Should have answered before reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. If you need more information, lookup `convert -rotate` in the manual